# Is there a way to stop vertical movement of rows in RowsSupportFragment when the focus moves from one Row to another in android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I have been trying to halt the vertical movement in the RowsSupportFragment. I have two rows and I want them to be displayed all the time on fixed positions.

In android TV whenever the focus moves vertically in Rows, next row moves up and leaves its original position. I want it to be fixed vertically.

Please help me solve this if there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to keep the focus point fixed?

The following code will make the position of focus fixed to first row:

```
    // Item alignment affects focused row that isn't the last.
    getVerticalGridView().setItemAlignmentOffset(0);
    getVerticalGridView().setItemAlignmentOffsetPercent(0);
    // Push rows to the top.
    getVerticalGridView().setWindowAlignmentOffset(0);
    getVerticalGridView().setWindowAlignmentOffsetPercent(0);
```

`getVerticalGridView().setWindowAlignment(VerticalGridView.WINDOW_ALIGN_LOW_EDGE);`

Check the following link for more details:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/VerticalGridView